# Get distance from point to 10 nearest points in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, distance, proximity

I've a layer with the location of different sampled ponds and a layer with all the ponds in the region. I want to calculate the mean distance to the 10 nearest ponds in the region for each of the sampled ponds. I used point distance to get all the distances but there is no option to only get the 10 nearest distances. Because of the amount of data it will be very intensive to manually search for the 10 nearest.

Comment: Have you tried Near, or Generate Near table?

Comment: Thanks generate near table did the job!

Answer (score 0):

Try tool [Generate Near Table](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/generate-near-table.htm):

> Calculates distances and other proximity information between features
>   in one or more feature class or layer